# Getting undefined for specific values in scope of angular js ng-model

Tags: angularjs, onpress

When I use `ng-model` for an attribute it’s become `undefined` in the `$scope` but I can see the values in `document.getElementbyid(cardinfo)`.

1. This `undefined` happens only for specific parameters. In the same page I can get access other fields.
2. We use `aem` for content management and AngularJS

In this page we have `onpress` for credit card format check method

Comment: It could be useful to clarify what's _eam_.

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Adobe Experience Manager Sites is a content management system within AEM that provides one place to create, manage and deliver digital experiences across websites, mobile sites, and on-site screens (like what you may see in retail stores or hotels).